# My Guinness is mixing into my harp and not staying separated, any trouble shooting ideas?

Tags: beer-cocktails

My Guinness is mixing into my harp and not staying seperated! Any trouble shooting ideas? Half and half trouble!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some troubleshooting tips I've found ([source](http://www.beeradvocate.com/food/recipe/9/)):

> Hold your pint glass at an angle, and fill just over halfway with Harp
>   or Bass.
>
> Rest the spoon upside down over the center of the glass, and pour the
>   Draught Guinness over the spoon which will evenly disperse the flow
>   and keep the Guinness from mixing -- the Guinness needs to be on the
>   top.
>
> Serve while the nitro is still cascading.

If they're mixing, my guess is that the Guinness is not being poured carefully enough, so that would be where I'd start.

Comment: Don't forget: Practice. Practice. Practice.

Comment: Drink the Guinness, drink the Harp; jump up and down; next time you see it will be mixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can spend a little bit of money and get a [Beer layering Tool](http://www.iwantoneofthose.com/gift-beer/beer-layering-tool/11151751.html?utm_source=googleprod&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=gp_gifts&affil=thggpsad&switchcurrency=GBP&shippingcountry=GB&gclid=Cj0KEQjwz-i3BRDtn53Z5Z7t4PUBEiQA23q2ACzyY6I_E2ongOsK9atW11aMGwWg6RXIfmrbZ9Qs7IwaAu038P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds&dclid=CL_b4paO5ssCFUIg0wod1UMByg) I have on of these and it is really helpful *almost* impossible to mess up